# Is $f(y) = 5 - 4y^2 + y^4$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Using Eisenstein's criterion, we can easily verify that $f(y)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. However, I'm not sure how I'd go about proving whether or not $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$. Does the fact that all of $f$'s roots are imaginary immediately tell us that $f$ is irreducible (I don't think this is the case since $f$ is quartic)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(y) = 0$ has complex roots, which form two conjugate pairs. If $f(y)$ were to be reducible over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt5)$, then the irreducible factor must be of degree 2, with the roots being one of the conjugate pairs.

$f(y) = (y^2 + \sqrt 5)^2 - (4+2\sqrt5)y^2 = (y^2 + \alpha y + \sqrt5)(y^2 - \alpha y + \sqrt5)$, where $\alpha$ is the square root of $4 + 2\sqrt5$.

In $\mathbb Q(\sqrt5)$, you need to figure out whether $4 + 2\sqrt 5$ is a square. But the norm $N(4+2\sqrt5) = 4^2 - 4\times 5 = -4$, so it cannot be a square of something.

Therefore, $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 5)$.

Comment: I understand why the irreducible factor must be of degree $2$, with the roots being one of the conjugate pairs. But in the next paragraph why have your written $f(y)$ as $(y^2 + \sqrt{5})^2 - (4 + 2\sqrt{5})y^2$? How does this relate to the previous paragraph?

Comment: So we know that if $f$ is reducible, it factors into real polynomials of degree 2, and there is only one such factorization. I then tried to give the factorization.

Comment: Does the fact that there is only one factorization of $f$ into two real polynomials of degree 2 follow from the fact that $\mathbb{R}[y]$ is a UFD?

Comment: It follows from the first paragraph. If a real polynomial has complex roots, they have to be conjugate.

Comment: Thanks for your help. One last question: what kind of norm are you using when you write $N(4 + 2\sqrt{5})$?

Comment: That is the absolute norm of the field extension $\mathbb Q(\sqrt5)$ over $\mathbb Q$. In particular, $N(a+b\sqrt5) = (a+b\sqrt5)(a-b\sqrt5)$

Answer (score 2):

Having all imaginary roots does not do it.  For example, $y^4 + 3 y^2 + 1$ has all imaginary roots, but factors as $(y^2 + (3-\sqrt{5})/2)(y^2 + (3+\sqrt{5})/2))$.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have already addressed your question about the roots, so let me just add that you can still apply Eisenstein's criterion when testing for irreducibility over $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$.

Presumably you applied Eisenstein's criterion to $f(x+1) = x^4 + 4 x^3 + 2 x^2 - 4 x + 2$ at the prime $p = 2$, and in fact this same strategy works over $K$.
The ring of integers $\DeclareMathOperator{\O}{\mathcal{O}} \O_K$ of $K$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ where $\alpha = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$. The minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is $x^2 - x - 1$ and since this is irreducible mod $2$, then $(2)$ is a prime ideal of $\O_K$. Applying the [general version of Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion#Generalization) at the prime ideal $(2)$ shows that $f$ is irreducible in $\O_K[x]$ and Gauss's Lemma then implies that $f$ is irreducible in $K[x]$.

I think this idea works more generally, too. Let $L \supseteq K$ be an extension of number fields, let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $\O_K$ that is unramified in $\O_L$, and let $\mathfrak{P}$ be a prime divisor of $\mathfrak{p} \O_L$. If $f \in K[x]$ is Eisenstein at $\mathfrak{p}$, then $f \in L[x]$ is Eisenstein at $\mathfrak{P}$.